# Proper subclassing of class clusters

Tags: ios, objective-c

After watching iOS tech talks and reading up on class clusters I decided to extract legacy iOS 6 code to a private subclass:

```
@interface MyUIView : UIView @end           // public
@interface MyUIViewiOS6 : MyUIView @end     // private
@interface MyUIViewiOS7 : MyUIView @end     // private

@implementation MyUIView
+ (id)alloc
{
    // Don't loop on [super alloc]
    if ([[self class] isSubclassOfClass:[MyUIView class]] &&
        ([self class] != [MyUIViewiOS6 class]) &&
        ([self class] != [MyUIViewiOS7 class]))
    {
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
            return [MyUIViewiOS6 alloc];
        } else {
            return [MyUIViewiOS7 alloc];
        }
    }

    return [super alloc];
}
// Common implementation
@end

@implementation MyUIViewiOS6
// Legacy code
@end


@implementation MyUIViewiOS7
// iOS specific code
@end
```

This implementation works well until I want subclass MyUIView.  For example if I create a subclass:

```
@interface MyRedUIView : MyUIView @end
```

and then init it like that:

```
[[MyRedUIView alloc] init]
```

object of type MyUIViewiOS6 or MyUIViewiOS7 will be allocated instead.  Is there a way I can adapt this pattern to support subclassing, so that superclass of MyRedUIView is dynamically switched to MyUIViewiOS6 or MyUIViewiOS7?

Comment: You need to add some more code. Where did `MyRedUIView` come from.

Comment: @Zaph That is what the OP is asking about: how to subclass a class cluster. MyRedUIView is the subclass.

Comment: @David Sure but the OP should provide what has been tried as he did with `MyUIView`, `MyUIViewiOS6` and `MyUIViewiOS7`, The OP just added that.

Comment: Your `+alloc` could be simplified to just: `if (self == [MyUIView class]) {return iOS7() ? [MyUIViewiOS7 alloc] : [MyUIViewiOS6 alloc];} else {return [super alloc];}` (assuming you've implemented `BOOL iOS7()` function somewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reached the classic double-inheritance problem. You want to be either a `RedUIView` or `GreenUIView` and be either a `MyUIViewiOS6` or a `MyUIViewiOS7` view.

Since objective-c does not support double-inheritance, you'll have to decide the difference between what you are, and how you act. Anything that determines what you are, you put in the class. Anything that determines how you act goes into a `@protocol` which then can be implemented.

I would subclass `MyUIView` since `MyUIViewiOS6` and `MyUIViewiOS7` correspond to who you are, and then implement a `Red` or `Green` protocol for certain functionality:

```
@interface MyRedUIView : MyUIView<RedProtocol> @end
```

You can check to see if this class conforms to a specific protocol:

```
 if ([class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RedProtocol)]) {
    self.color = [UIColor redColor];
 }
```

If both of them ***really*** are who you are, then you have to use four separate classes.

---

Here's an example using categories. Assuming that you have MyUIView as specified in the question:

**GreenView.h**

```
#import "MyUIView.h"
#import "Green.h"

@interface MyUIView (GreenUIView) <Green>

-(BOOL) isGreen;

@end

@interface GreenView : MyUIView @end
```

**GreenView.m**

```
#import "GreenView.h"

@implementation MyUIView (GreenUIView)

-(BOOL) isGreen{
    return [self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Green)];
}
@end

@implementation GreenView @end
```

**Green.h**

```
@protocol Green <NSObject> @end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "GreenView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    GreenView* view = [[GreenView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [view isGreen]?@"yes":@"no");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: If `MyUIView` is declared as in the question then surely your `conformsToProtocol` call will return `NO`? Can you clarify how your solution works?

Comment: You can have one super class `MyUIView` and two subclasses: `@interface MyRedUIView : MyUIView<RedProtocol> @end` and `@interface MyGreenUIView : MyUIView<GreenProtocol> @end`

Comment: If `MyUIView` is defined as in the question, with `MyUIViewiOS6`  or `MyUIViewiOS7` being selected by the `alloc`, then `@interface MyRedUIView : MyUIView<RedProtocol> @end` will *not* return `YES` to `conformsToProtocol`, or provide the protocols methods etc. - because it is actually one of two private classes. Maybe I'm being thick, but it is not clear from your answer whether you are removing those two classes (and the corresponding selection in the `alloc`), or doing something else. And if you are removing those two classes, what is the benefit of the protocol?

Comment: Updated the answer with a functional example

Comment: Your added code does not match the your original answer. In the answer you have `MyRedUIView` implementing the protocol, in the added code it is `MyUIView` which implements the protocol. The original answer does not work. While the added code works as far as it goes, if you define `RedView` following the same pattern then you will discover that a `GreenView` instance returns `YES` for `isRed`...